# Can i create user, database and collection in mongo Docker?

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm following the Mongo documentation for create init user with database and collection on first start of container, but when i create user with readWrite permissions i can't access my "dashboard" database with the collection "person_file_upload", with permission denied warning.

I just want to create an non-root user to read and write my database only. Is anything wrong with my script?

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:4.4.3-bionic
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: mypassword
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: admin
    volumes:
      - ./proativa-dashboard-mongo/data:/data/db
      - ./proativa-dashboard-mongo/init/mongo-init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:ro
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:27017:27017"
    networks:
      - mongo
    container_name: mongo
```

```
db.createUser({
    user: 'dashboard',
    pwd: 'dashboard',
    roles: [{
        role: 'readWrite',
        db: 'admin',
    }]
});

db = db.getSiblingDB('dashboard');
db.createCollection('person_file_upload');
```

Comment: Did you try following the logs of the container while running this command?

Comment: @MarkoE Yes, i can't see nothing wrong in the logs. This script creates user, database and collection, but i have no permissions with "dashboard" user.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the database specified in the createUser function and the database you specified when connecting to the DB. Try connecting as the admin and create the user with the dashboard database in the roles array in the createUser function